# How Spring maps URL and where to read more about it

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, mapping

I'm new to Spring. I'm trying to learn it by doing instead of reading. So I found some stuff which is confusing. But it works. I want to know why and how?

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/ok")
    public class MyController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/ok", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView findAllAccounts() throws Exception {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("account");
            mav.addObject("someText", "Listing all accounts!");
            return mav;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/ok/{accountId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView findAccount(@PathVariable int accountId, Model model) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("account");
            mav.addObject("someText", String.format("Showing account %d", accountId));
            return mav;
        }   
    }
```

For above code I found that.

working Get request url : http://localhost:8080/ok/

working Get request url : http://localhost:8080/ok/ok/888

But I was expecting url : http://localhost:8080/ok/ok/  should also work. But it doesn't work. Why? If http://localhost:8080/ok/ok/888 works why http://localhost:8080/ok/ok/ doesn't work?

Also when I deploy it in tomcat. It only works if named ROOT.war. If I change to XYZ.war, it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".

Comment: It should work. Request to http://localhost:8080/ok/ok/ will be mapped to `findAllAccounts()`. What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: "I'm trying to learn it by doing instead of reading." - Just out of curiosity, why ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `http://localhost:8080/ok/ok/` does not work as it treats your last `ok` as your `accountId` and it fails conversion to an integer. The best documenation is [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)
2. Your question about tomcat - I believe it should be fine with another name, only then you would have to access it as `http://localhost:8008/XYZ/`